# Form does not submit with php echo

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, posting

I have the following code:

index.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
    echo "<script>alert(".$_POST['val1'].")</script>";
  }
?>

<html>
...
<body>
...
<?php
  echo "<form id='form_id' method='post' name='myform'>";
  echo "<input id='val1' type='text' value='7'>";
  echo "<input id='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>";
  echo "</form>";
?>
...
<body>
</html>
```

This will create a form, a text field and a submit button. All those shown perfectly fine except it would not submit the form. So my question is why does my form not work here and what should I do to solve this problem without moving it out from php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are missing `name` attributes for the elements:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
    echo "<script>alert(".$_POST['val1'].")</script>";
  }
?>

<html>
...
<body>
...
<?php
  echo "<form id='form_id' method='post' name='myform'>";
  echo "<input id='val1' name='val1' type='text' value='7'>";
  echo "<input id='submit' name='post' type='submit' value='submit'>";
  echo "</form>";
?>
...
<body>
</html>
```

You can notice the addition of `name` attribute for text field and submit button. Only `name` attribute will be used to identify the fields when form gets posted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thamilan's answer about the name attribute you should use *empty*($POST['val1']) instead of *isset*. 
Here is a complete working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<?php
if (empty($_POST['val1'])) 
  print "<title>Not yet submitted</title>";
else 
{
  echo "<script>alert(".$_POST['val1'].")</script>";
  echo "<title>Submitted</title>";
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  echo "<form id='form_id' method='post' name='myform'>";
  echo "<input name='val1' id='val1' type='text' value='7'>";
  echo "<input id='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>";
  echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```